# why does my db session commit doesn't work?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to update my profile but my db.session.commit() doesn't work in IDLE, and when I try on PythonShell, it works. I don't know why, please help me. Sorry for my english

```
@app.route('/edit/<username>',methods=['POST','GET'])
@login_required
def edit(username):
  form = ProfileForm(request.form)
  if request.method=='POST' and form.validate():
     t_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
     t_infor = Infor.query.with_parent(t_user).filter_by(user_id=t_user.id).first()
     t_infor.phone = form.phone.data
     t_infor.mail = form.mail.data
     db.session.commit()
     return redirect(url_for('profile',username=username))
  return render_template('edit.html',form=form,username=username)

@app.route('/profile/<username>')
@login_required
def profile(username): 
  t_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
  t_infor = Infor.query.with_parent(t_user).filter_by(user_id=t_user.id).first()
  ifmt=[{
  'name': t_user.name,
  'phone':t_infor.phone,
  'mail':t_infor.mail
  }]
  return render_template('profile.html',username=username,ifmt=ifmt)
```

Comment: Does this line " t_infor = Infor.query..."  returns a result?

Comment: There is lot of code missing in your question, but you can read my answer about forms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52907155/9871463). You are probably haven't set CSRF token in form, enctype maybe, maybe you are not sending POST request... Be sure to check all that.

Comment: @gittert yes, it does

Comment: I'm not seeing any evidence regarding adding the updated `t_infor` to session. Please add and then commit.

Comment: Do you have any error log?